# Library for producing consumer-playable DVDs

Tags: .net, dvd, vob

So I have an application that creates VOBs as a step for DVD creation. I am using StandardMPEG encoder, and it works like a charm.

Burning actual .ISO isn't my concern here, but building it is.  I need a library that is able to create simple menu, mark some chapters for the VOB, and finally create an ISO that should be burned. I would be happy with directory also.

I'm looking for a free solution, or at least one that has a one-time fee, not 'give-me-your-shoe-size-we-tell-you-the-price' packages.

And one more thing-I need .NET lib, preferably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this http://dvdauthor.sourceforge.net/ it is C, so you might need to work on it a little.